What is the source of the motto of the Border Roads Organisation (B.R.O), Shramena Sarvam Sadhyam?
What is the source of the motto of the Border Roads Organisation (B.R.O), Shramena Sarvam Sadhyam?
Is it mentioned in any of the hindu scriptures? If yes, then which one exactly? If no, then where did this idea even come from?
